# Удаление данных из истории GIT

Tags: git, github

Случайно запушил в публичный гит репозиторий данные API ключей, надо как-то удалить, но все попытки ничем не увенчались. Как можно избавится от этих данных в истории репозитория?

Пытался через интерактивный ребэйс `git rebase -i HEAD~4`

Но получил

```
line 267: mate: command not found
Could not execute editor
```

Comment: Надеюсь, вы уже сделали эти ключи недействительными?

Comment: @andreymal я удалил репозиторий и залил по новой.

Comment: Ключи-то, ключи недействительные?

Comment: @andreymal пока не разобрался как это сделать.

Comment: Обязательно разберитесь, потому что злые хакеры давно успели скачать ключи из старого репозитория и уже готовятся напакостить вам

Comment: Он пытается запустить TextMate (наверное? командой `mate`) для редактирования сценария интерактивного ребейза, но команды `mate` нет. Вы TextMate'ом собирались сценарий редактировать?

Comment: @D-side да кажется такая попытка тоже была.

Comment: попробуйте явно указать имеющийся в наличии редактор: `$ EDITOR=vim git rebase ...` (или `nano`, или `mcedit`, или что у вас там установлено).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе нужно сначала откатить локальные изменения по ветке до нужного тебе комита, а потом сделать форс пуш.

**АККУРАТНЕЕ, ЭТО УДАЛИТЬ ВООБЩЕ ВСЕ ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ ПОСЛЕ ВЫБРАННОГО КОММИТА**

скопируй все на всякий случай.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~4
git push origin HEAD --force
```

Твоя команда сработала, если бы ты не пушил изменения, а так нужно заменять удаленную ветку.

Comment: На самом деле удалённые коммиты останутся доступны по прямым ссылкам, проверено на гитхабе

Comment: @andreymal, там раз или несколько раз в сутки запускается скрипт на подчистку orphaned комитов, так что не надолго. Но вы правы, ключи надо инвалидировать, тогда можно не морочить голову с force push, а просто делать revert.